# how to test an application after uploading it in google play store

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have added a new feature in the app. It should be published as an update of existing app.
I have upload it for alpha testing. Now I need to test the app. I don't know how to proceed.
Please tell me the steps to be followed after uploading the application from the play store. My company didn't provide me the proper information so need your help.

Comment: *My company didn't provide me the proper information* you should look for another job ;-)

Comment: nice so u come here for advising me not for the answers

Comment: I wasn't serious. Sorry if you found that inappropriate. I will remove it if you like

Comment: its okay Tim Castelijns.I am little bit tension yesterday on testing the app so only replied like that i will consider your suggestion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you’re starting a new alpha/beta test, it’s a good idea to start with a small group of alpha testers, then expand your test to a larger beta test group.

You could follow the instructions given on this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).

Comment: yes i have read it.But i have not yet added to the test groups

Comment: You have to add the test group, once you done that, they (group members) will recive a mail. And your app will only be visible to them.